# Cron expression for last day of each quarter

Tags: laravel, command, schedule

I want to run a schedule command of last day of each quarter in laravel. But I checked that when use quarterly function, it really run on first day of quarter but it is not what I want. Any suggestion?

Comment: There isn't a method to target the last day of each quarter (that I know of); you'd have to manually determine those. However, knowing that the first day of a quarter is only a day off from the last day of the previous quarter, could you not modify your command to target the previous day? What does this command do that makes a days difference significant?

Comment: Or, you could create your own frequency based on [`->lastDayOfMonth()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ManagesFrequencies.php#L546), i.e. `->lastDayOfQuarter()`, using `return $this->spliceIntoPosition(3, Carbon::now()->endOfQuarter()->day);` (but would need custom logic to handle different months)